# SQL - Retrieve records from database with a couple of conditions

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following database:

```
Account  Month   Pass

1        July    No
2        July    No
3        July    Yes
4        July    No
5        July    Yes

1        August  No
2        August  Yes
3        August  Yes
4        August  Yes
5        August  Yes
```

I want:

1) things that failed in July, but passed in August
2) the same account numbers from the previous query, but in August and not July

So the results of the previous examples would be :

```
Account  Month   

2        July    
2        August
4        July
4        August
```

Comment: Writing a general query here could be difficult, because you don't have actual dates in your table, you just have yearless month names.  Consider storing actual dates.

Comment: The actual dates in the database are in the format dd-mm-yy

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with the results for a given account in one *row* rather than multiple rows, then `join` should do what you want:

```
select j.*, a.pass
from july j join
     august a
     on j.account = a.account
where (j.pass = 'yes' and a.pass = 'no') or
      (j.pass = 'no' and a.pass = 'yes');
```

That said, I strongly encourage you to put the data in a *single* table with a date column, as Tim suggests in a comment.

Comment: I miswrote my original question. They actually *are* in the same database

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.Account from temp a where a.Month = 'July' and a.pass = 'No'
INTERSECT
select a.Account from temp a where a.Month = 'August' and a.pass = 'Yes'
```

or

```
select a.Account from temp a where a.Month = 'July' and a.pass = 'No' 
and a.Account in (select a.Account from temp a where a.Month = 'August' and a.pass = 'Yes')
```

or

```
select * from temp a, temp b 
where a.Account = b.Account and a.month <> b.Month 
and a.Month = 'July' and a.pass = 'No' and b.Month = 'August' and b.pass = 'Yes'
```

You can use same query for your question 2, just change conditions

Comment: Does this return the results for August as well?

Comment: Could you make clear your question? All my query return accounts not month, to get month you can easy to change "select * from" into "select a.Account, a.Month, b.Month" a.Month always return 'July' and b.Month always return 'August'

Answer (score 0):

> I donot have teradata. The following query works fine in mssql. Should be same in most sqls barring some syntactic changes

You would have to do a join on the account number (the identifier) to identify the account numbers with the fail/pass conditions across tables the below query helps in that.

```
select select a.AccountNumber from dbo.MonthlyResultAugust a join dbo.MonthlyResultJuly b on a.AccountNumber=b.AccountNumber where lower(a.Pass)='yes' and lower(b.Pass)='no';
```

Then for the desired output, you can union both the source tables and extract data matching the account numbers from previous query.
The combined query will look like

```
    select AccountNumber, Month from 
(select * from MonthlyResultAugust union select * from MonthlyResultJuly) as combined
 where accountNumber in 
 ( select a.AccountNumber from MonthlyResultAugust a join MonthlyResultJuly b 
 on a.AccountNumber=b.AccountNumber where lower(a.Pass)='yes' and lower(b.Pass)='no') order by AccountNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
SELECT Account, [Month]
  FROM pass_table t
 WHERE [Month] = 'July' AND Pass = 'No'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pass_table [Month] = 'August' AND Pass = 'Yes' AND Account = t.Account)

UNION

SELECT Account, [Month]
  FROM pass_table t
 WHERE [Month] = 'August' AND Pass = 'Yes'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pass_table [Month] = 'July' AND Pass = 'No' AND Account = t.Account)
```